# AvalonDock 2.0 editable header

Tags: avalondock

I'm using Avalondock version 2.0 and set into the header custom editable texbox control.
But when I changed the header text, the message does not invoke to the 
ViewModel(see at `<Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.DataContext.Caption, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"`).
What can I solve this?

```
    <xcad:DockingManager Grid.Row="1" regions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static   common:RegionNames.DesignerRegion}" 
                         Style="{DynamicResource CustomDockingManagerStyle}">
        <xcad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <behaviors:EditableTextBlock x:Name="EditableTextBlock" 
                                             Text="{Binding Path=Title}"
                                             TextBoxBorderColor="#C34442"
                                             TextBlockForegroundColor="{DynamicResource AddButtonBackground}"
                                             TextBoxForegroundColor="#7B3A3A"
                                             TextBoxBackgroundColor="#FFF1E6"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                             VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </xcad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
        <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
            <avalonBehaviors:PanesStyleSelector >
                <avalonBehaviors:PanesStyleSelector.DocumentsStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.DataContext.Caption, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Style>
                </avalonBehaviors:PanesStyleSelector.DocumentsStyle>   
            </avalonBehaviors:PanesStyleSelector>
        </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
        <xcad:LayoutRoot >
            <xcad:LayoutPanel >
                <!--xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                    <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane />
                </xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup-->
                <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane />
                <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane DockWidth="250" >
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Properties" AutoHideWidth="250"> 
                        <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static common:RegionNames.PropertiesRegion}"/>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
            </xcad:LayoutPanel>
            <xcad:LayoutRoot.BottomSide>
                <xcad:LayoutAnchorSide>
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Log Messages">
                            <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding LogMessage}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                </xcad:LayoutAnchorSide>
            </xcad:LayoutRoot.BottomSide>
        </xcad:LayoutRoot>
    </xcad:DockingManager>
```

Thanks